# Need to track variables from multiple Tkinter checkboxes

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a dynamically created Tkinter checkbutton widget, which takes in the contents of a list of usernames. I then displayed those names with a checkbox alongside.

What I need to do is obviously collect which usernames have been checked, so I can pass that off to another function to action.

How should I write the variable part of this so it creates a new list of chosen usernames?

What I have thus far:

```
def delprof_results(users_delprof):

    for i in range(len(users_delprof)):
        c = Checkbutton(resultsFrame, text=users_delprof[i], variable=users_delprof[i])
        c.pack(anchor=W)

    def delprof_del():
        users_chosen = []
        print str(users_delprof[i]).get() # Works up until this point. How to get individual variable with ID.

    del_but = Button(resultsFrame, text="Delete", width=7, height=1, command=delprof_del)
    del_but.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Comment: What do you think `c` finally is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reach individual objects, simply keep a reference to the individual objects instead of creating objects while overwriting the same variable with each iteration of a loop like:

```
for i in range(30):
    a = i
```

How to reach `a`'s state where it was `13`? Well, you *can't* as it's overwritten.

Instead, use collection types. In the example below I used `dict`:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def upon_select(widget):
    print("{}'s value is {}.".format(widget['text'], widget.var.get()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    names = {"Chester", "James", "Mike"}
    username_cbs = dict()
    for name in names:
        username_cbs[name] = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=name,
                                                onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        username_cbs[name].var = tk.BooleanVar()
        username_cbs[name]['variable'] = username_cbs[name].var
        username_cbs[name]['command'] = lambda w=username_cbs[name]: \
                                                                upon_select(w)
        username_cbs[name].pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Nae, it took me a while to get my head around what you'd put, but that does what I need, so thank-you!!

Comment: Update: The above adds to  the list upon selection, but I also need it to remove from the list on de-selection. How should I add that functionality in to the above code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of values from the checkbuttons:

```
values = []
for i in range(len(users_delprof)):
    v = IntVar()
    c = Checkbutton(master, text="Don't show this again", variable=v)
    c.var = v
values.append(v)
```

Now you can check the value by looking in the list `values`, and getting the value of a checkbutton with `v.get()`.